# URL not working around the SVG graphic

Tags: html, css, svg

I gave my logo in SVG format, and put `<a>` tag around the `object` element. But my anchor tag isn't working its just shown a 10px height under the svg graphic. Look at my code, that will give a clear picture what I'm talking about..

```
<a href="#" class="logo">
<object data="images/tc_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:100%;">
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <img src="images/tc_logo.png">
<![endif]-->
</object>
  </a>
```

and I gave logo class as `display:block` but its not working..

CSS

```
.logo{
width: 100%;
height: 210px;
display: block;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

**EDITS MADE**

At last I've found one solution, I know its not the right way but if you aren't ready to step back with SVG.. try this..

Use html like this..

```
<span style="display:block; position:relative;">
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <object data="images/tc_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:100%;">
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
      <img src="images/tc_logo.png">
    <![endif]-->
    </object>
</span>
```

and css would be..

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    height: 210px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9
}
```

hope you got the trick..

Comment: Any specific browser? works on firefox, though am not using `svg` but you can take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/KSHtF/

Comment: @MR.Alian actually it'll work fine if you not using svg graphic.

Comment: You'd need to put the link inside the svg content if you want this to work. You can't put links round replaced elements like this and have them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one ugly way:

```
<a href="#" class="logo">
    <![if gte IE 9]>
       <img src="images/tc_logo.svg">
    <![endif]>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <img src="images/tc_logo.png">
    <![endif]-->
</a>
```

Live [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnYQZ/).

This won't work on the old android browsers though, so it's probably better to look into other options, such as replacing all svgs with png fallbacks as soon as you detect a lack of svg support (requires javascript). See e.g http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/19965/svg-with-png-fallback/p1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making your SVG an image tag rather than an object tag, alternatively you may get away with this slight hack!

```
<a href="#" class="logo">
    <span style="display: block;">
        <object data="images/tc_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:100%;">
        <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
          <img src="images/tc_logo.png">
        <![endif]-->
        </object>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks. I've a question Steve.. if we use it in image tag IE having problems, img tags get displayed twice in IE. one with blank that is SVG, the other one is PNG image..

Comment: This is the draw-back with using the image tag - IE backward compatibility is a problem. The slight hack should work in this case.

Comment: @SteveFenton since you're using conditional comments anyway, nothing really stops you from using <img> instead of <object>. However, what you're suggesting won't work on e.g old android browsers.

Comment: @ErikDahlström I presume you mean the "use an image" solution won't work - but the slightly hacky solution still would wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use CSS to remove a pointer event. The `object` appears to supersede the anchor tag event, so removing it appears to re-activate the anchor tag:

```
.logo object {pointer-events:none;}
```

Note that I used only Chrome to do this for now and didn't test it everywhere.